# Assinar projeto em flutter com a mesma keystore de um projeto já publicado

Tags: flutter, google-play, keystore

Me surgiu uma duvida tenho uma aplicação feita em kotlin no android studio já publicada na loja porem descobri o flutter e gosto mais de usar ele como linguagem, eu estava pensando em refazer esse projeto em flutter, eu consigo assinar ele com a mesma keystore do projeto já publicado na loja e enviar como uma atualização?

Comment: nunca passei por isso, mas desde que seu app mantenha o mesmo applicationID creio que não haverá problemas na hora de publicar

Comment: Mudar a tecnologia utilizada para criar o app não tem problema. O app deve ter o mesmo nome de pacote e ser assinado com a mesma chave. Já fiz app com java que mudou para ionic e mudou para kotlin, sempre atualizando sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta: Sim!

Eu já fiz isso, na verdade era um projeto legado feito com `Ionic` e o meu trabalho era refazer utilizando Flutter. A única coisa que você precisa se atentar é que o app Flutter precisa ter o mesmo package name do app feito em nativo. Então, sugiro que você rode o seguinte comando na hora de criação:

```bsh
flutter create --org=com.suaorganizacao nome_do_projeto
```

Assim ele vai gerar um pacote: `com.suaorganizacao.nome_do_projeto`, ainda existem opções mais complexas no comando `flutter create` vale a pena você executar `flutter create --help` para ver todas as possibilidades.

Também, quando for efetivamente subir o app, vai ter que compilar com um version code superior ao que está publicado.

Dentro do seu pubspec.yaml vai ter uma chave escrito version:

Seguindo o exemplo abaixo, o "1.0.0" é o versionName e o número 1 após o símbolo de mais é o versionCode.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma se você já tiver compilado `30` versões do seu app e você está na versão `1.0.6`, o nome da sua próxima versão seria algo como:

```yaml
version: 1.0.7+31
```